# Css is not loading in MVC4 razor layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have added the CSS in the _Layout but it is not loading the CSS or any Javascript Files

I have folder structure like this

```
Assets/Css/admin/... so on
```

In my MVC4 razor layout I am loading the css like this rather using Bundles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Assets/css/admin/module.admin.stylesheet-complete.min.css")" />
```

but its not loading the css according to this pattern. I used the same in MVC3 razor layout and it worked.

After loading clicking the url generated in rendered form in browser it shows

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error</title>
```

Contents of my Css File

```
@import '../../../Assets/components/common/forms/editors/wysihtml5/Assets/lib/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5-0.0.2.css';
```

What seems to be the problem with MVC4 ?

Please guide

Comment: how does your html render with the css file?

Comment: How does the `<link rel=""....` html look in your source code generated by the browser?

Comment: like this <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Assets/css/admin/module.admin.stylesheet-complete.min.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Thanx all I have figured it out. I have changed the project setting to Annonymous Authentication to Enabled and Windows Authentication to Disabled. The problem is solved by doing this. Thank you for your efforts